# create embed document with parent embed id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have embedded document in my schema

```
var option = new mongoose.Schema({
option: {type: String, required: true},
nextItem: {type: String, required: true}// here I want to add next embedded document(item) id
});
var item = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        options: [option],
        createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
        parentItem: {type: String, required: true}, // here I want to add previous embedded document(item) id
    });

    var category = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {type: String, required: true},
        items: [item]
    });
```

based on item selected by user , I have to show another item. How can I get next and previous embedded documents id while saving on mongodb

Answer (score 0):

See the [population section](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in node.js documentation :)

Below i modified your schema's (you maybe have to correct the schema names)

```
var option = new mongoose.Schema({
option: {type: String, required: true},
nextItem: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Option' }// here I want to add next embedded document(item) id
});

var item = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        options: [option],
        createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
        parentItem: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }, // here I want to add previous embedded document(item) id
    });

    var category = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {type: String, required: true},
        items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }]
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but here I want next item id not option id, so it would be 
nextItem: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }, right?
and another question is, how can I add objectId at the time of saving on mongodb, Because I don't know next item id when creating

Comment: Yes then change it to Item (or whatever you called it). You can also update the item when you do know the next item. Or stick with the parentItem options. option & item seem similar, where you store a item in option and a option in item...